# Clarification of the statement of the Pumping Lemma

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

In class we were told that Pumping Lemma states:

"Let A be a regular language over $\Sigma$. Then there exists k such that for any words $x,y,z\in\Sigma^{*}$, such that $w=xyz\in A$ and $\lvert y\rvert\ge k$, there exists words $u,v,w$ such that $y=uvw$, $v\neq\epsilon$, and for all $i\ge0$ the word $xuv^{i}wz\in A$."

I was informed by the professor that one cannot make choices on what $x,y,z$ are in the above Theorem when you wish to prove a language is not regular. I'm probably missing something incredibly easy but if you assume (for the purpose of contradiction) that a language is regular does the above statement not guarantee for all choices $x,y,z$ such that $xyz\in A$ and $y$ is sufficiently long that the conclusion of the Pumping Lemma holds? Perhaps a quantifier is missing?

Any clarification to the statement of the Pumping Lemma would be appreciated. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. If you want to *apply* the lemma to a language you know (or assume) is regular, you can choose $x$, $y$, and $z$ any which way you fancy, as long as you make sure $y$ is long enough. (But since you get $k$ *from* the lemma, what you actually need in the usual scenario is to provide is a procedure that explains *how* you're going to choose $x$, $y$, and $z$ after you know what $k$ is).

In light of this, your professor's statement is rather peculiar. Perhaps he was referring to *proving* the lemma? If your task is to prove the lemma rather than apply it, the burden of proof switches around, and you now have to find a way to deal with whatever $xyz$ your adversary shows up with (after you tell him a $k$).

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. Just to be clear on usage of this version of the pumping lemma, if I wanted to prove the language $\{w:w\in\{a,b\}^{*},w=a^{2k}b^{k}\,\text{for}\,k\ge0\}$ is not regular I can assume (for contradiction) that it is regular, then obtain $m\ge0$ from the pumping lemma. Then can I choose $x=a^{2m}$, $y=b^{m}$, and $z=\epsilon$ which satisfies the length criteria for $y$?

Comment: @user99163: Yes.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Have a good day.